# Constant state transition probability table: speed of convergence metric needed

Tags: markov-chain, transition-matrix

I have the state transition probability table: $A=a_{ij}$ where $i$ - the initial state, and  $j$ - end state. Of course, $$\forall i:\sum_jA_{ij}=1$$
In the infinity all initial state vectors would converge to some final equilibrium state $e$ such that $\forall x, \sum_j x_j=1$ we have $$xA^\infty=e$$

I can calculate the final state using eigen decomposition $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$, so $e=Q\Lambda^\infty Q^{-1}$, where $\Lambda^\infty$ matrix has just one cell on the diagonal equal to 1, the rest is zeros. The reason is that $\Lambda$ has the highest eigen value equal to 1, and the rest are $<1$, so they disappear.

Now, I need some measure of how any fast the initial states $x$ converge to the final state $e$. The intuition is that if I had a function $y=y_0e^{-\lambda t}$, then $\lambda$ would characterize the speed of decay. So, I
d like to get something like this for the entire matrix $A$.

UPDATE:
It seems that there is a rate of convergence according to [this paper:](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~lorek/files/lorek_thesis.pdf)
$$e-A^k=$$, they have en example on p.16. So, it appears that $\lambda_2^k$ is the rate of convergence.

Comment: Look at the other eigenvalues.

Comment: @whuber, this is not a home work :) Can you elaborate? You mean something like a condition number in SVD? I found something which seems relevant though http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/313/ConvergenceRates.pdf

Comment: Since $A^k=\left(Q\Lambda Q^{-1}\right)^k=Q\Lambda^k Q^{-1}$ it suffices to study the entries in the *diagonal* matrix $\Lambda^k$.  They are (obviously) the $k^\text{th}$ powers of the eigenvalues.